# PHP Connection to remote MySQL server failure

Tags: php, mysql

I am hosting a site on some free hosing website called 'freewebhostingarea.com' and for this particular project when I had it running locally on my Apache it worked quite fine but when I uploaded it to the server I can't access the same database which is being hosted on my computer at home. So initially I was running the site under WAMPP using phpmyadmin as the DBMS but when I moved the site I imported the .sql file from phpmyadmin into Workbench and provided external access to root account and to test this I can remotely connect to this database over the Internet from another computer. But the site itself if giving this error:

> Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

But the script to access the database has this code:

```
<?php 
mysqli_connect('url','username','password');
echo mysql_error();
mysql_select_db('database');
echo mysql_error();
?>
```

I am failing to understand why it is even using 'apache' as username when I have specified the username to use?

Comment: Replace `password` by the password you are given to mysql

Comment: check if you are trying to connect from any other place(s) in code.

Comment: @Sree I am using actual username and password, in the actual code...I just used 'password' here for demo purposes

Comment: @bansi I checked, the only file that requires the connection is this dB.php and that's all the code to it

Comment: in that case you should be getting error message `Access denied for user 'username'@'url' (using password: YES)`

Comment: don't use both `mysql` and `mysqli`.`mysql` is depreciated don't use it

Comment: @bansi let me hunt thru the code again, but I didn't put anywhere else to ask for connection unless the web hosting has something to do with it?

Comment: @FastSnail changed :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this
[Go to this page and found your mysql username and password](http://doms.freewha.com/cgi-bin/amanager.cgi)

```
<?php
$usernmae = '996869';
$password = '996869';
$dbname = '996869';

$db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project2");
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
} 
?>
```

Comment: sorry I went to the page, its just the main page for the Control Panel...where exactly should I find that information?

Comment: Oh I get your point...just a sec...you meant changing my code to thid

Comment: Yeah you can login your control panel

Comment: Now it's just loading forever

Comment: NICE! It gave a connection timeout!

Comment: Can't connect to MySQL server on "myIP"(110) let me troubleshoot from here... thanks

Comment: send screen shot please. I hope fix your problem.

Comment: It's under alpro.freeoda.com

Comment: You can't access the site?

Comment: Oh yes...that started after changing the code...it actually timesouts after 60 seconds then brings up the error 101 which is quite weird although good in the fact that atleast it's now directing to mySQL server but somehow it can't get a connection

Comment: Yup the server in on my Desktop, so the PHP is trying to connect to it

Comment: Can have your Facebook?